# laravel handle json child array

Tags: php, jquery, json

For my project I try to create an ajax call and handle the data.

My Ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        url: ****,
        data: {****},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data.rooms);
            $('.pagination').html(data.paginate);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('failure');
        }
    });
```

On the server with laravel I create a response with:

```
return response()->json(['rooms' => $rooms->toJson() , 'paginate' => $bathrooms->render()]);
```

In my ajax call the json response [looks like](http://jsonblob.com/55d9b502e4b01190df3623fb) (Edit this is the original json):

```
  {"rooms": "{\"total\":3,\"per_page\":9,\"current_page\":1,\"last_page\":1,\"next_page_url\":null,\"prev_page_url\":null,\"from\":1,\"to\":3,\"data\":[{\"id\":237,\"name\":\"Modern met allure\",\"description\":\"Badkamer blablabla\",\"collection_id\":187,\"style_id\":7,\"created_at\":\"-0001-11-30 00:00:00\",\"updated_at\":\"-0001-11-30 00:00:00\"},{\"id\":243,\"name\":\"TIjdloze charme\",\"description\":\"Tijdloze charme\",\"collection_id\":187,\"style_id\":2,\"created_at\":\"-0001-11-30 00:00:00\",\"updated_at\":\"-0001-11-30 00:00:00\"},{\"id\":245,\"name\":\"Staande badkraan Bollicine\",\"description\":\"blablabla\n\",\"collection_id\":199,\"style_id\":7,\"created_at\":\"-0001-11-30 00:00:00\",\"updated_at\":\"-0001-11-30 00:00:00\"}]}","paginate": ""}
```

Now I want to loop all the object in data so First I tried:

```
 console.log(data.rooms);
```

this gave me the first part i wanted (only the rooms not the something_else, next I tried to get only the data part by

```
console.log(data.rooms.data);
```

But then the result is

```
 undefined
```

How should I access/loop through the data (subpart of rooms).

Comment: does `console.log(data.rooms)` work?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Yes this gave me the first part I wanted (only the rooms )

Comment: What is the real ajax response? Because in json there can't be `'`, only `"` What do you use to encode data on server?

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with the string.  Can you try the following? `console.log(data.data)`

Comment: Sorry i tried to edit my string, its very long so tried to  customize it here.

Comment: @u_mulder Edited with he original json

Comment: Have you tried to foreach on your data.rooms ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem that you have two `data` here. One is variable name and second is key name.
Try to use either:

```
console.log(data.rooms["data"]);
```

Or choose another name for `success` argument:

```
success: function(roomsdata){
    console.log(roomsdata.rooms);
    $('.pagination').html(roomsdata.paginate);
},
```

**UPDATE**: on seeing how you generate json on server:

```
return response()
    ->json([
        'rooms' => $rooms->toJson() , 
        'paginate' => $bathrooms->render()
    ]);
```

You're doing double json encoding: first encoding `$rooms` to json with `toJson()` and then encoding json-string to json again with `json()`. Remove `toJson()` call, leave only `json()`.

Comment: u_mulder tried both, both times i get undefined. I copied the object with chrome and it has alot of backslashese for some reason, (see edited question). Could that be a problem?

Comment: Maybe it does, remove  `toJson` from `$rooms->toJson()`

Comment: Tried it now i get bathrooms as object but i cant open or view the object it looks like:  rooms : Object
__proto__: Object

Comment: And can you access `rooms.data` (`rooms["data"]`)?

Comment: I've ended up using this solution https://gist.github.com/tobysteward/6163902#file-blogcontroller-php-L6 everything is working now